# regular expressions to string in c#

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have to use regular expressions in a c# application and I try to use it as a string to use regex.match method. My regular expression is like `id="(tt[0-9]+)\|imdb` and I convert it to string like `"id\"(tt[0-9]+)\\|imdb"` but it doesn't work. Do you have any solutions or applications that convert regexes to strings??

Comment: your string is missing the = is that intentional?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can drop the escaping and use a @ sign.

```
@"id=""(tt[0-9]+)\|imdb"
```

Note: you have to double the doublequotes

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you are trying to accomplish, so I am going down a different path then the other posts.

The `Regex.Match` method should take the `String` you are trying to match against, it sounds like you are attempting to go backwards from a constructed RegEx to a String. If that is the case simply call `ToString()` on the RegEx to get the passed in expression.

If you are simply trying to get the expression as a String then the `pattern` var below would so that making use of the @ as mentioned in the other posts. Either way though, the `RegEx` itself should contain the pattern you want to match against.

```
  string text = "91919182389348487";
  string pattern = @"id=""(tt[0-9]+)\|imdb";

  Regex r = new Regex(pat, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
  Match m = r.Match(text);
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

In C#, it is a good idea to add a `@` before strings containing reg exps:

```
 @"id\"(tt[0-9]+)\\|imdb"
```

Otherwise the regexp engine would only see this string:

```
  id"(tt[0-9]+)\|imdb
```

where `\|` is not recognized the way you want it.

Comment: Good advice, not-so-good explanation.  In the verbatim string version the `\"` needs to be changed to `""` and the extra backslash in `\\|` should be removed.  But the OP's regex is well formed for a non-verbatim string.  I suspect the real problem was the missing `=`, as @AndrewCox pointed out in his comment.